# Connect to OpenVPN server from Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: gui, openvpn

I have a number of ovpn files that allow me to connect to different OpenVPN servers. These files work well on Windows platform using the OpenVPN community edition utility. Each requires a username, password and password for the key.

My ovpn have the ca, cert and key within the ovpn file itself (not a problem to extract each to its own file).

I tried setting up the connections in the *Setting -> Network* with certificates as **Password with Certificates**.

[image]

It is not connecting.

1. Is there a guide I can follow?
2. Is there a GUI I can use that uses the ovpn file rather than have me set the settings in dialog option?  In the Network setting I have to redo everything in the advanced tab.
3. In OpenVPN client on windows I have a log. Is there something equivalent here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to import the opvn file and as it wasn't in the OpenVPN subsection I missed it.

If you have the OpenVPN settings they can be imported through the **Import from file** option.

One interesting this is that if the configuration file has the various certificates embedded in it the function will autogenerate the various files itself.

[image]